# Positioning label when using labeled control

Tags: html, css

Okay, trying to create a fillable form that has inline fillable forms (think Mad Libs-style).

For an element using labeled control and given the following code:

`<form><p>Lorem ipsum <label class="label__fill-in"><input type="text" class="fill-in" maxlength="30">(community)</label> and stuff</p></form>`

Is it possible to position the label text "(community)" below the input line without using `for="id-name"` (referred to in the MDN as a "labeled control") using only CSS? What would the selector be for only the true label text and not the input within it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather that trying to move the text, make the input block element which will cause the text to be below it.

Based on your structure, I imagine that you are looking to get the text outside of the label to be in line with the input.  So in order to do that, make the label `display: inline-block` so that it gets the height that you want.  Then you can align the text of the `p` to the top so that all the text lines up.

https://jsfiddle.net/foyxhz4y/

The css that I used for this is:

```
label input {
  display:block;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
}

p * {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

To select contents of the label that are not inputs, you can use the `:not` selector.  So to style the text you can use:

```
label *:not(input)
```

This will select all contents of the label that are NOT an input element.